# Setting up "Single Sign On" In Php(laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, single-sign-on, saml, simplesamlphp

I wish to setup `Single Sign On` by both setting up (Identity Provider) **IDP** and (Service Provider) **SP** for practice. I studied about it and found `SimpleSAMLphp` to be only viable option,

**Now My question is there any out of the box package exist through which I can setup my IDP server using Laravel?**

P.S. For SP I am thinking https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2
I know the question is kind of vague, but I am looking for different options,  and even after lot of research, I am not able to find it, So any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yes it is vague but, you can use [SimpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp) as Identity Provider to achieve what you need.

Comment: @MozammilKhodabacchas I find that it was the only option present, is there any other?

Comment: That is the only one I know of. I also particularly like what [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) provides.